# HTML5 / Jquery upload - debug code, because proble.m with rewriting files

Tags: jquery, html, upload

UPDATED

How i can hold added files by input field?

I created this script: http://jsfiddle.net/dyzg9qa8/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('input').on('change', function(event) {

        var img = this.files;
        var show = '.s_' + $(this).attr("class");

        $.each(img, function(index, f) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e){
                $('<img src="' + e.target.result + '" width="450">').appendTo(show);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        });
    });
});
```

and html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="images">Multiple Images</label>
    <input type="file" class="img1" name="img[]" multiple accept="image/*">
    <div class="s_img1"></div>

    <hr>

    <label for="images">Multiple Images</label>
    <input type="file" class="img2" name="img[]" multiple accept="image/*">
    <div class="s_img2"></div>

    <input type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

when for eg. I add two images to the input will be displayed below,
and as I click again on the input and I will add one more picture of this will be added to these two below. So now I have 3 pictures below.

but when I type in php "print_r" in the form displays only the last value of the input.
in $_FILES only is submit last value of input. I want send all values added before,
how to do this ? :)

regards!

Answer (score 2):

the `name=""` attribute is what defines the variable name in PHP.

So having two tags with `name="img"` will make the 2nd overwrite the first.

You'll need to do one of the following:

`name="img[]"`

This makes the name `img` an array and when PHP receives it, it can `foreach` through `img`

or you can do `name="img1"` and `name="img2"` for PHP to pick them up separately.

You should also be using the `$_FILES['img']` variable to access files (including images) uploaded to the server.

Comment: not works, after changes in $_POST i see only last added file / files, when i add 3 files and add 2 files then in $_POST i see only last 2 files :/

Comment: `$_POST` shouldn't even be picking up the file. You should be using the `$_FILES` variable to access files.

Comment: the same situation :/ i use $_FILES, on question I made a mistake

Comment: if you can, please download and try with php ;)

Comment: Just tested it. It works fine in PHP. Keep in mind the $_FILES array structure is `$_FILES['img']['name'][0]` - `$_FILES['img']['name'][1]` etc.

Comment: I now: use only one input, 1. Add three images, 2. Add two new image by the same input.

below you have 3 image loaded by jquery/html5, now click submit,

enter <?php print_r($_FILES); ?> and checkout output of print_r.
In output you can show only one last two added images

Comment: As I said, it's working. Your EXACT HTML is working.

Comment: Well that's because you're overwriting the value of the input box.

Comment: when i use this http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/filedrag/2/index.html i overwrite input and on submit form are send all values, how to do that these values are kept?

Comment: You should just look into dropzoneJS

Comment: dropzone is to large script, my have 14 lines, but I still only need this function(kept values).